# Gatling - Set Request name dynamically

Tags: scala, gatling

Can I define a rquest name dynamically? I tried that with `http(s"/product${prID}"`but I am getting an error (variable prID not found):

```
    val searchByProductIdTask = exec(http(s"/product${prID}")
        .post(appURL + "/api/product/search")
        .headers(jsonHeader)
        .body(StringBody(my_string_body)).asJSON
        .check(status.is(200), responseTimeInMillis.lessThan("${expectedResponseTime}"))
    ).pause(5)
```

UPDATE:

Here the whole code:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

import java.time.Instant

class Product_Szenario extends Simulation {

val scenarioName = "Test_Product"

val baseURL="My_Base_URL"

val appURL="My_URL"

val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL(baseURL)
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0")       
    .connectionHeader("keep-alive")
    .disableWarmUp
    .disableCaching

val jsonHeader = Map(
    "Accept" -> "*/*",
    "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
    "X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest")

object Product {

    val searchByProductIdTask = exec(http(s"/product${prID}")
            .post(appURL + "/api/product/search")
            .headers(jsonHeader)
            .body(StringBody("""{"prID":"${prID}"}""")).asJSON
            .check(status.is(200), responseTimeInMillis.lessThan("${expectedResponseTime}"))
        )
}

object Szenario{

    val products = csv("product.csv").records
    val filialFeeder = csv("filial.csv").circular //50%

    val start= exec(repeat(products.size, "n"){
        feed(products.queue)
        .feed(filialFeeder)
        .exec(Product.searchByProductIdTask)
        .pause(5)
    })
}

val scnProduct = scenario(scenarioName)
    .exec(
        session =>{ 
            session.set("appUrl",baseURL + appURL + "/")
            .set("expectedResponseTime", 20000) // set to time you want check fails - find long time responses
        }
    ).exec(
        Szenario.start
    )

setUp(
    scnProduct.inject(atOnceUsers(1))//, First Scenario
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use string interpolation, you have missed the `s"${expectedResponseTime}"` in the second to last line!

```
val searchByProductIdTask = exec(http(s"/product${prID}")
        .post(appURL + "/api/product/search")
        .headers(jsonHeader)
        .body(StringBody(my_string_body)).asJSON
        .check(status.is(200), responseTimeInMillis.lessThan(s"${expectedResponseTime}"))
    ).pause(5)
```

Comment: The problem is in the http(s"/product${prID}"). I would like to generate the request name depending on the value of variable prID

Comment: It’s fine that should work what is the error you are getting did you tried to print the (s”/product$prId”)?

Comment: I am getting a compile error. The variable prID doesn't exist (`not found value: prID`)

Comment: that means you didn't even defiend the variable prID first defiend it then only you can use the variable that's the problem, if you can post the full code i could have known that you didn't even defiend the variable and using it.

Comment: The variable is in the session, I have checked right now

Comment: can you post the full code so i can see what the problem is.

Comment: You still don’t have the prID variable in your code how you can use it? You said before it’s in session I don’t know how you have a variable in session?

Comment: From where you are getting the product id? From a get call a post call or what how you are getting the value?

Comment: Because the variable comes from a feeder csv("product.csv")

Comment: Why you are not using saving it in your program when you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
        val searchByProductIdTask = exec(session => session.set("request_name", s"/product${session("prID").as[String]}"))
        .exec(http("${request_name}")
        .post(appURL + "/api/product/search")
        .headers(jsonHeader)
        .body(StringBody("""{"prID":"${prID}"}""")).asJSON
        .check(status.is(200), responseTimeInMillis.lessThan("${expectedResponseTime}"))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get rid to get rid of the s and make it -

```
http("/product${prID}")
```

By using string interpolation the compiler is looking for a Scala string variable named prID, but prID is a Galing session attribute, so you can just use Gatling EL to bring it into the request name.